# What is the troubleshoot for this error: conversion of .SRA to FASTA file on command prompt?

Tags: fasta

I am getting this error message after using the following code:

```
C:\sratoolkit.3.0.7-win64\sratoolkit.3.0.7-win64\bin>fastq-dump --fasta SRR1658345
```

Error:

```
2023-12-11T06:08:04 fastq-dump.3.0.7 err: timeout exhausted while waiting condition within process system module - failed SRR1658345

=============================================================

An error occurred during processing.
A report was generated into the file 'C:\Users\Hp/ncbi_error_report.txt'.
If the problem persists, you may consider sending the file
to 'sra-tools@ncbi.nlm.nih.gov' for assistance.

=============================================================

2023-12-11T06:09:46 fastq-dump.3.0.7 err: connection failed while opening file within cryptographic module - Cannot KStblHttpFileTimedReadChunked: to=0
```

What should be done?

[Link to ncbi error report](https://pdf.ac/22SpHj)

Edit:
I am on Windows, using Command Prompt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are doing. First of all , tel us your operating system. Are you running Windows or some reason? If yes, what exactly are you running? Is that WSL? Or are you running it from a Windows shell? Also, please upload that error report to something like https://pastebin.com instead of making it a pdf. We need to be able to copy text from it and that site doesn't allow copying.

Comment: Isn't the syntax   `  --fasta <line-width> where <line-width> can be
                                     "default" or "0" for no wrapping"  `

Comment: @Sam I don't think so. I just tried running `fastq-dump --fasta SRR1658345` on my Arch Linux machine and it brought me a fasta file just fine.